# Defining an area for a screen capture on android

Tags: java, android, screenshot, android-mediaprojection, android-virtualdisplay

I currently have a `VirtualDisplay` set up using the `MediaProjection` API which is being drawn on to a `SurfaceView` that is always visible. The VirtualDisplay is, however, capturing the entire display but I would like it do capture only the portion of which the SurfaceView is covering. Is there any solution to this, I would appreciate the help?

[image]

Comment: Can't you [set the screen size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.projection.mediaprojection.createvirtualdisplay?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12) when creating the VirtualDisplay?

Comment: That just sets the size of the VirtualDisplay, which still contains the entire screen.

Comment: I've read around and it seems impossible to do with this API, try reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API), if it's not out of date it should do the trick.

Comment: I am using Java, please refer to the appropriate documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise, try [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-capture-screenshot-of-a-view-and-save-it-to-gallery-in-android/) guide, from the mini introductory video it looks like it only screens the logo, so not full screen.

Comment: if you want to record surface,you can use recordablesurfaceview https://github.com/spaceLenny/recordablesurfaceview

Comment: Thank you for that but I do not need to save a recording to a file, I simply want to achieve what is shown in the image. @Eugenio this does not really help because he is simply saving the image that is being held in the View.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352523/android-crop-video-from-mediacodec-in-surfaceview) question, I have found a solution. Setting the `SurfaceView`'s scale was the key:

```
mSurface.setScaleX(/*scale factor*/);
mSurface.setScaleY(/*scale factor*/);
```

As for the scale factors, I am currently trying with trial and error until I get a perfect fit and it blends in perfectly with the background, but I will try to do it in a more programmatic and precise manner.